# How do I validate email addresses

Tags: jquery, validation

I would need some help with validating email addresses.

I am aware of the basic validation which allows users to only fill in '*@*.com'

However, I would like to take it one step further by only allowing email addresses like Gmail / Hotmail / Yahoo to be keyed in.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could you please explain more the context within you try to achieve this ?

Comment: if you have a fixed domain name like gmail ,hotmail and yahoo. you can create regex pattern with the domains names. or else if you want anything else lets explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression in javascript to **common email validation** like :

```
var validEmail = function(email) {
  var expression = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
  return expression.test(email);
}

//Usage
if(validEmail('somename@domain.some')){
    //Do something
}

//Return True
console.log(validEmail('somename@domain.some'));
```

Or **only allows** email addresses like **Gmail / Hotmail / Yahoo** :

```
//Return true if valid email is passed
var validEmail = function(email) {
      var expression = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
      return !expression.test(email);
    }

//Usage
if(validEmail('somename@gmail.com')){
    //Do something
}

//Return False
console.log(validEmail('somename@domain.some'));
//Return True
console.log(validEmail('somename@gmail.com'));
```

If needed add **more domains** to expression it makes like this:

```
var expression = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)(?!outlook.com)(?!me.com)(?!msn.com)(?!ymail.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
```

In this case I add Yahoo, Hotmail and some...

And one more variant with strict validatin:

```
//Return true if valid email is passed
function isEmail(str) {
  var allow = ["gmail.com", "hotmail.com", "yahoo.com"];
  for(var i = 0; i< allow.length; i++) {
    if(str.indexOf(allow[i]) != -1) {
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

//Return True
console.log(isEmail('somename@gmail.com'));
```

Live example how it works - https://jsfiddle.net/Coderius/L6gqvy3n/